# Terminal Has Two Environments in Parentheses

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, anaconda, zsh

While trying to set up Google Colab so I could access a ton of large jpgs for a CNN, I was running into problems. In my flustered state I tried to follow a now-forgotten website's advice. It did not work. But what did happen was now my terminal has two virtual environments (I think) listed one after the other. I'm on a macbook pro, using Zsh.

```
(firstEnv) (myenv) johndoe~$
```

I would prefer to revert back to having just my virtual environment

```
(firstEnv) johndoe~$
```

I tried:

```
conda deactivate myenv
```

but nothing changes

Comment: Have you tried simply closing the Terminal window and opening a new one?  If the changes you made were not persistent then that should clear them.  Otherwise, the fact that the changes are persistent will considerably narrow down where to look for them.

Comment: I'm kind of embarrassed. That worked @JohnBollinger. Thanks a ton. If you'd like, turn your comment into and answer and I'll mark it as correct and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've made *non-persistent* changes to your shell environment inside a Terminal window, then you can discard those changes by simply closing that window and opening a new one.

If persistent changes were made then they would have been effected by updating one or more files, (probably) in your home directory. For Zsh, these would be one or more of `.zshenv`, `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, and `.zlogin`.